# Odd python driver files in micropython for esp32 and esp8266 cause make errors

Tags: makefile, build, esp32, micropython

I've been trying to build a micropython for esp32-camera and I keep getting errors during the make process when building some of the drivers in the mp/ports/esp32/modules directory.  The error I get is a syntax error.  For example there's a file named ntptime.py in this directory and it contains a single line:
../../esp8266/modules/ntptime.py
and that results in "SyntaxError: invalid syntax"
I've programmed python for a while, but am not familiar with this concept and don't understand how it can work, but maybe it can?  I'm not familiar with doing that and since it's not working when I run make, maybe there's something setup-wise that I've missed or whatever.  Can anyone shed some light on this practice and explain under what circumstances this works to direct make (or the python compiler) to resolve this statement by loading the source from the directory specified in that single line of code.

Comment: Not seeing that file: https://github.com/micropython/micropython/tree/master/ports/esp32/modules.  Where'd you get your source?

Comment: cloned the micropython distro from github

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Duh, can't believe I missed this:  there "files" are symbolic links;  I should've remembered that, but alas, I'm getting older by the minute!
Still, it doesn't answer the question as to why they weren't being recognized during make but instead throwing a SyntaxError; but I'll leave that for another day.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this as your answer. Even "duh" moments can help the next person. ;-)